# Why is operator<< overload changing values of my variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am expanding on a interview question I had. I created a Rectangle class and instantiated a few of them. I encountered a problem when the deconstructors are called. r1 was fine. r2 caused a crash. So I manually called the deconstructors and noticed it was crashing on r2. I thought maybe it was linked to r1 when it was deleted but that was not it. The problem started before.

I am changing the point value of r2 and printing it out. The change was fine till I get to the cout. 
The value of point changes when entering my overloaded operator <<. The incoming variable rect get garbage for the point, which changes r2.

Setting r2's point and printing out:

```
r2.SetPoint({ 6.0f, 1.0f }); // Move r2
std::cout << "After moving r2: " << &r2 << std::endl;
```

My overloaded operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, Rectangle* rect)
{
    return out << "x: " << rect->GetPoint()->x
        << " y: " << rect->GetPoint()->y
        << " width: " << rect->GetDimensions()->width
        << " height: " << rect->GetDimensions()->height;
}
```

Why is r2 changing from the print statement?

To see all my code see [my repository](https://github.com/codarth/ProgrammingTest).
(Please feel free to give me advice on my code and standards)

Edit: I think it is in my constructors. I remove the two lines and I still get the error. Looking up at my constructors the values initially are fine then the next line they go bad.

Comment: You should condense only the code causing the issue down into a [mcve] and edit that into your question. External links and repos go bad and then the question isn't useful to anyone else. It appears that your copy constructor and assignment operator are both broken. Count how many points are created versus how many are destroyed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I did not know I could not add images till reputation of 10

Comment: Images are bad, too. Relevant [mcve] please.

Comment: Since you also asked for advice, here it is: Stop using pointers for things you do not need pointers for.

Comment: Start by changing your function to this `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, Rectangle const* const rect){...}` and you will see what is conceptually wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the print statement. The actual issue occurs because of the way you defined `SetPoint` function.

```
r2.SetPoint({ 6.0f, 1.0f });
```

When you do this, the below function will be called.

```
void Rectangle::SetPoint(Point2D _point)
{
    this->point = &_point;
}
```

Please note that it is passed by **value**. If you see it closely, you will get to know that it will lead to Undefined Behaviour. Why? Consider this:

```
void Rectangle::SetPoint(Point2D _point)
{
    this->point = &_point; // this->point points to _point object.
} // _point dies here. So, accessing this->point will lead to UB.
```

**Suggestions**:

1) Destructors are not necessary to be called explicitly. You did it in main.cpp. Once the object goes out of scope, destructor is called automatically.

2) Your code has memory leak.

```
Point2D* point = new Point2D;
Dimensions* dimensions = new Dimensions;
```

If I call `SetPoint()` and `SetDimensions()`, the pointer to the dynamically allocated memory will be lost.

3) Define Getters as `const` functions.

4) Avoid Shallow Copying in your scenario. It will create problems that will be harder to trace.

Comment: Maybe this is where my confusion is. Does not the this->point point to the object SetPoint belongs to, the Rectangle? not _point?

Comment: @Codarth When you called the function `SetPoint`, a local object `_point` was created with value `{ 6.0f, 1.0f }`. When you did `this->point = &_point;`, Now, your `this->point` points to local object, `_point` which will die once the function ends.

Comment: Suggestion #1: I know. I just did that for testing.

Comment: That makes sense.